# How to choose which scene shows up first spritekit/swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Where is it declared which scene will show up first on load up of the app? The first file I made which is the game obviously shows up first, but if I'm wanting to switch it so that my main menu pops up first, how and where do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view controller, the first scene is set. By default, it's automatically set to GameScene but you can change this by altering the code in the GameScene. You should change this line in unarchive from file: 
`let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene` to 
`let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! sceneName` 
and this line in didMoveToView 
`if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {`
 to 
`if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? sceneName {`

This will cause the game to load sceneName, or whatever you scene is called as the initial scene.